# DPM won't synch due to a non-existent file

Tags: backup, scdpm

DPM 2007

Server with issue is Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition

DPM is reporting that "DPM encountered an error while performing an operation for C:\program files\vexira antivirus\server\temp\aa29n3f0.vbt (ID 2033 Details: The parameter is incorrect (0x80070057))"

The problem is that the file isn't there and I am not finding any open file handles referring to that file as being held open (did a search using procexp.exe for handles or dll strings).

The temp subdirectory did have misordered permissions when I checked them, but I told Windows to reset the permissions and verified that applications should have access to the subdirectory and it no longer complained about access issues.

Anyone else run into this issue before with DPM?

Comment: Any VSS snapshots (`vssadmin list shadows` should list them)?

Comment: @ChrisS: No items found that satisfy the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly a solution to the synch issue, but if you cancel the sync and do a consistency check it should resolve the issue and allow you do create a manual recovery point (or wait for the next scheduled one).

Comment: Worked. Don't know why, can't explain it. There was an order-of-ACL's issue before this on that subdirectory, perhaps that interfered with it at some point and created an inconsistency that made DPM's head rattle.

Comment: Thank you. Had this error for quite some time and tried *a lot*. Now I found the consistency check option only in the "Protection" menu, not in the "Monitoring" menu, DPM 2016.